# Is this summation $> 0$ or $< 0$?

Tags: summation

Sum:

$$
s =\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{p-1} v_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^{p-1} v_i\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^p} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^{p-2} v_i^2
$$

Where $0<p<1$ and $a_i, v_i$ are real numbers.

EDIT - also $a_i$ > 0

Comment: No it's not. Sorry I will edit to make more clear.

Comment: Just to clarify, is that what you want to calculate?
$$ s = \frac{\big(\sum_1^n a_i^{p-1} v_i\big)\big(\sum_1^n a_i^{p-1} v_i\big)}{\sum_1^n a_i^p} - \sum_1^n a_i^{p-2} v_i^2 = \frac{\big(\sum_1^n a_i^{p-1} v_i\big)^2}{\sum_1^n a_i^p} - \sum_1^n a_i^{p-2} v_i^2 $$

Comment: @YoungMoney  You get stacked fractions with \frac {top}{bottom}

Comment: What about the possibility $=0$?  That can certainly happen if, for example, $a_i=v_i=1$ for all $i$.

Comment: @Integral - yes exactly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an application of [The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality):
$$
\left|\,\sum_{i=1}^na_i^{p-2}a_iv_i\,\right|
\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i^{p-2}a_i^2\right)^{1/2}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i^{p-2}v_i^2\right)^{1/2}\tag{1}
$$
Squaring $(1)$ and dividing by $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^{p-2}a_i^2$ and subtracting $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^{p-2}v_i^2$ yields
$$
\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^{p-2}a_iv_i\right)\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^{p-2}a_iv_i\right)}
{\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^{p-2}a_i^2}-\sum_{i=1}^na_i^{p-2}v_i^2
\le0\tag{2}
$$

Comment: Alright, so it the sum > 0 or < 0?

Comment: @YoungMoney: applying what I have stated above, $s\le0$.

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble applying it, could I see a few steps?

Comment: (probably should have asked for help showing in question title rather than only asking for answer, my bad)